# Calling Main( ) from another class

Tags: c#, program-entry-point

I have a class named `TestMaze`. I have another class named `DisplayHome` which has a method called `gameOver()`:

```
public void gameOver()
    {
        Console.Write("GAME OVER!");
        Console.Write("Play Again? Y/N");
        if(char.ToLower(Convert.ToChar(Console.Read())=='y')
            //Main()
        else
            Environment.Exit(1);
    }
```

How can I call the Main method?
PS. they have the same namespace. I just need to know how can I call the Main method again.

Comment: Why do you need to call the `Main` method?

Comment: aw why did you voted down? >.< the code explains why. >.<

Comment: You don't want to call `Main` again. As the answers below indicate, you need to refactor your code so that your `Main` method calls a `StartGame` function (or equivalent), and then call *that* function to play again.

Comment: @Reinan: Since downvotes on questions are free, people downvote all naive questions. Not that this is a great question, but I don't think one should be this aggressive towards it

Comment: @Armen I know why people downvotes. But i think i'm not supposed to be downvoted. anw, thanks guys.

Comment: @Reinan: I don't think you should be downvoted either :) But apparently people just aren't nice any more :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a Play() method inside your Main... and GameOver() should call Play() if user enters 'y'.

Comment: that's a good suggestion. i haven't thought of that. I'm used to goto;

Answer (score 4):

Refactor your code. Move whatever needs to be called into another function, and call it from both, main, and gameOver.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `Main` is a static class method (which I'd imagine it is) you can simply use `MyClass.Main(/*relevant args*/)` - beware of course that it's going to be a fresh instantiation, it won't share any non-static variable data.

A possibly better solution however would be to put all your code into a separate class which is invoked/instantiated from `Main()` - your program can then pass a boolean back to the actual executable Main which will be used to decide whether or not to exit or loop.

Comment: And make sure `Main` has a proper protection level. `protected static int Main` will cause some extra work