# How do I call Main from another class?

Tags: c#, console, console-application, calculator, program-entry-point

So I am making a C# Console Program that is a simple calculator, I am just learning C#.

Here is where I want to call main:

```
if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
else
{
}
```

I want to call main for the Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication and Division classes so it goes back to the start to where it asks 'Press 'A' for Addition' etc.

I tried putting "Main();" in else but it gives me and error saying *"There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'args' of 'Program.Main(String[])"*

How could I go about calling main in this class so it goes to the start of main?

Comment: Why do you want to call Main?  Have main call another function to start your app.  You can then call that function instead of Main.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling Main( ) from another class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723558/calling-main-from-another-class)

Answer (score 6):

You wouldn't call `Main` yourself it's used as an entry-point into the application. Usually you'd call out to the other methods, for example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   while (true) 
   {
        Console.Write("> ");
        string command = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

        if (command == "add")
        {
            Add(); // Call our Add method
        }
        else if (command == "subtract")
        {
            Subtract(); // Call our Subtract method
        }
        else if (command == "multiply")
        {
            Multiple(); // Call our Multiply method
        }
        else if (command == "exit")
        {
            break; // Break the loop
        }
   }
}

static void Add()
{
    // to-be-implemented
}

static void Subtract()
{
    // to-be-implemented
}

static void Multiply()
{
    // to-be-implemented
}
```

Another thing to note here is it's `Main(string[] args)`, the `args` parameter contains an array of arguments passed on the command line to the console application.

If you *were* to call `Main` yourself you would need to pass a value to this, for example:

```
Main(null); // No array
Main(new string[0]); // An empty array
Main(new string[] {}); // Another empty array
Main(new string[] { "Something" }); // An array with a single entry
```

Comment: Whilst this works, I think it would be much better to have a method along the lines of `GetCommand` rather than placing the logic in `Main`

Comment: @DarrenYoung It's only a quick example.